# Problem during ReactNative project deployment for iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, react-navigation, npm-start

I'm developing a brand new iOS/Android app and I want to use a single code, so I decided to use ReactNative for my pourpouses, and I want to build myself the executable instead of using something like Expo for remote building, so I bought a MacMini where I connected my Android and iOS physical devices (where i'll run my project).

I'm using VisualStudioCode as IDE and did all the passages to install ReactNative (v0.73.5) and everything goes well, I have my base project that runs perfectly using

`npm start`

and running both version on my devices without problems.

The problem came when I try to add *navigation-container* in my project; I followed the guide (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) and installed native stack navigator library too (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation) and write a simple code to automatically switch from project start (App.tsx) to a splash page, like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import SplashScreen from './screens/SplashScreen';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and run it using **npx react-native run-ios** and **npx react-native run-android**.

On Android everything works well, and I land in my splash screen as I intended, but on iOS I can't even build and run anything: using npx i got this error

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ETMHOMECROSS-avqdpcaltzlgykcghamktxvqeiyk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNScreens/RNScreens.framework/RNScreens normal (in target 'RNScreens' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

while using **npm start** and typing **i** the build stuck with no error while compiling

```
info Opening app on iOS...
info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Found Xcode workspace "ETMHOMECROSS.xcworkspace"
info Found booted iPhone 14 Development , iPad
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace ETMHOMECROSS.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme ETMHOMECROSS -destination id=00008110-000255322130A01E")

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 

Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace ETMHOMECROSS.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme ETMHOMECROSS -destination id=00008110-000255322130A01E

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Prepare packages

ComputeTargetDependencyGraph
note: Building targets in dependency order
note: Target dependency graph (61 targets)
    Target 'ETMHOMECROSS' in project 'ETMHOMECROSS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Pods-ETMHOMECROSS' in project 'Pods' via file 'Pods_ETMHOMECROSS.framework' in build phase 'Link Binary'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'CocoaAsyncSocket' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework CocoaAsyncSocket' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-CoreModules' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework CoreModules' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'DoubleConversion' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework DoubleConversion' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAnimation' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTAnimation' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTBlob' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTBlob' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTFabric' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTFabric' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTImage' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTImage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTLinking' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTLinking' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTNetwork' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTNetwork' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTSettings' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTSettings' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTText' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTText' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RCTTypeSafety' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTTypeSafety' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTVibration' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTVibration' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNCMaskedView' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNCMaskedView' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNGestureHandler' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNGestureHandler' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNReanimated' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNReanimated' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNScreens' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNScreens' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Core' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'ReactCommon' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework ReactCommon' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Codegen' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_Codegen' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Fabric' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_Fabric' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-FabricImage' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_FabricImage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-ImageManager' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_ImageManager' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Mapbuffer' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_Mapbuffer' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-NativeModulesApple' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_NativeModulesApple' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAppDelegate' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_RCTAppDelegate' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-debug' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_debug' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-graphics' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_graphics' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jserrorhandler' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_jserrorhandler' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-nativeconfig' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_nativeconfig' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-rendererdebug' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_rendererdebug' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-runtimescheduler' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_runtimescheduler' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-utils' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_utils' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'SocketRocket' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework SocketRocket' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-cxxreact' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework cxxreact' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'fmt' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework fmt' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RCT-Folly' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework folly' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'glog' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework glog' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsi' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework jsi' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsinspector' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework jsinspector' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsiexecutor' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework jsireact' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'libevent' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework libevent' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-logger' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework logger' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'react-native-change-icon' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework react_native_change_icon' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'react-native-safe-area-context' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework react_native_safe_area_context' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-hermes' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework reacthermes' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-perflogger' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework reactperflogger' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Yoga' in project 'Pods' via
```

I think I got some conflicts on Pods, but I can't get any info about what and how to resolve.

Any help, also on procedures to install dependencies in the right way, are welcome!

Thanks in advance

[UPDATE]

After removing node_modules folder, package-lock.json file and reinstall using

`npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context`

now I have more problems than before:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
- Ld /Users/telemed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ETMHOMECROSS-avqdpcaltzlgykcghamktxvqeiyk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNScreens/RNScreens.framework/RNScreens normal (in target 'RNScreens' from project 'Pods')
- Ld /Users/telemed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ETMHOMECROSS-avqdpcaltzlgykcghamktxvqeiyk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNReanimated/RNReanimated.framework/RNReanimated normal (in target 'RNReanimated' from project 'Pods') 
(2 failures)
```

Answer (score 0):

the error is saying that the RNScreens library is missing from your Podfile, but you are probably missing two install packages: react-native-screens and react-native-safe-area-context.
Uses:

```
npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

Or if you use yarn, replace npm install with yarn add
I also recommend that if it continues to fail, delete your **node_modules** folder and your lock file such as **package-lock.json** or **yarn.lock** and do the installation again, don't forget to enter your **ios** (`cd ios`) folder and use `pod install`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply.  I had already installed the two packages you mentioned following the official guide. However I tried to delete the folder and file you said and re-install anything (also Pods). Android works fine again, ios is getting worse :D

Now I had

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
      ...Debug-iphoneos/RNScreens/RNScreens.framework/RNScreens normal (in target 'RNScreens' from project 'Pods')
       ../Debug-iphoneos/RNReanimated/RNReanimated.framework/RNReanimated normal (in target 'RNReanimated' from project 'Pods')
(2 failures)

Comment: Have you tried removing the derived data and installing pods again?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Seems these people are as well.https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/2059

Answer (score 0):

Change the react-native-screens version to:

```
 "react-native-screens": "3.29.0"
```

There seems to be a issue with the current version of screens:
The Fix: https: //github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/2082

Other reports: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/2059

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention this is a IOS issue only.